# Keccak256 hashing of types and values in Java

Tags: web3j, keccak, java

I'm trying to use the Web3j library (or any other library for that matter) to Keccak256-hash a list of types and a list of values to sign a quote. Specifically, I need to implement the second code snippet from [this documentation](https://docs.hashflow.com/hashflow/market-making/getting-started#4.-support-signing-quotes), which is a JavaScript example.

I've tried to use Web3j and I've tried

```
Hash.sha3(Hex.encode("test".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
```

> From `byte[] Hash.sha3(byte[])` JavaDoc:
> `Keccak-256 hash function. | Params: input – binary encoded input data | Returns: hash value`

expecting it to result to `9c22ff5f21f0b81b113e63f7db6da94fedef11b2119b4088b89664fb9a3cb658` (typing `test` in [this tool](https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/keccak_256.html)), but that's not the case:

```
Expected :is [<57b>, <99b>, <50b>, <50b>, <102b>, <102b>, <53b>, <102b>, <50b>, <49b>, <102b>, <48b>, <98b>, <56b>, <49b>, <98b>, <49b>, <49b>, <51b>, <101b>, <54b>, <51b>, <102b>, <55b>, <100b>, <98b>, <54b>, <100b>, <97b>, <57b>, <52b>, <102b>, <101b>, <100b>, <101b>, <102b>, <49b>, <49b>, <98b>, <50b>, <49b>, <49b>, <57b>, <98b>, <52b>, <48b>, <56b>, <56b>, <98b>, <56b>, <57b>, <54b>, <54b>, <52b>, <102b>, <98b>, <57b>, <97b>, <51b>, <99b>, <98b>, <54b>, <53b>, <56b>]
Actual   :[<-40b>, <-18b>, <20b>, <101b>, <-125b>, <117b>, <-68b>, <12b>, <-110b>, <-12b>, <-20b>, <121b>, <88b>, <106b>, <-88b>, <75b>, <-51b>, <27b>, <69b>, <105b>, <-9b>, <-13b>, <27b>, <114b>, <28b>, <-67b>, <-20b>, <43b>, <96b>, <15b>, <121b>, <93b>]
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong and if this is the best approach at all? Maybe there are better libraries to use? There seems to be very little literature online for Java when it comes to this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Glad someone posted this, I am having issue too not getting correct address recovered from signature because of this because of mismatched SHA3 hash. I think there is something wrong with `Hash.sha3()` method.